# How to loop in my json intercepted by ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have an ajax call that returns me a numeric value (count) and an element with different values ​​(date). 
If the variable 'count' is greater than zero, I want to get all the elements 'data' returned using a loop.
Below is my JSON code and the script is returning.

Returned Json:

```
data: [{l:1, id:1, ddd:11, cel:123456-789, senha:123456, plano:},…]
0: {l:1, id:1, ddd:11, cel:123456-789, senha:67892, plano:}
1: {l:2, id:2, ddd:11, cel:123456-789, senha:27821, plano:}
2: {l:3, id:3, ddd:11, cel:123456-789, senha:27827, plano:}
3: {l:4, id:4, ddd:11, cel:123456-789, senha:14536, plano:}
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/checkErrors.php',
  success: function(resultErrors) {
     countErrors = parseInt(resultErrors.count);

     if (countErrors > 0) {
     // Loop in resultErrors.data elements and get l, id, ddd, cel, senha and plano.
     }
   }
});
```

How can I do this? 
Thank you.

Comment: `$.each(data, function(i, item) { alert(data[i].l + data[i].id + data[i].ddd ... );
});​`

Comment: is that a valid json??

Comment: @AnoopJoshi It is only returned by firebug example, is not the complete json.

Answer (score 0):

use $.each() function from jquery
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Hum I didn't see Pavlo answer.

For check is your data are in valid json use this tools online : http://jsonlint.com/